# 'Element not found.' while using pywin32 with Excel to open file

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32

I'm trying to open an Excel file called 'temp.xlsx using pywin32 using the following code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
excel.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/user_name/python_try/temp.xlsx')
```

While it worked for me for the past two weeks, yesterday I started getting the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147319765, 'Element not found.', None, None)
```

I rechecked lots of time and the path is correct, the file exits in 'normal' mode (not read-only or similar).

Tried to look everywhere and while I found similar cases where this error showed, the solutions suggested there didn't solve it.

The only changes I made python/Excel-wise before it stopped working was installing auto-py-to-exe lib and trying to generate exe from my program (which I uninstalled in hope it will return to work).

If it's relevant, working on Windows 10 machine, Office 365 (all updated), python 3.7.0.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually just solved it using try except like this:

```
 try:
    excel.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/user_name/python_try/temp.xlsx')
except:
    pass
```

Still if someone knows why it happened it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide me with a good pywin32 documentation and its limit, i think it is very powerful but i can't wrap my head around the documentation

Comment: Actually I have the same problem, that's why I couldn't find the problem. So unfortunately no